# jQuery Cycle plugin count not right to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

**[See my DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/efsp6wu2/)**

I have 4 divs under form.

JS:

```
$('.webform-component-radios div').cycle({
      fx:      'fade',
      timeout:  0,
      prev:    '#prev',
      next:    '#next',
      pager:   '#nav',
      after: onAfter
    });
    function onAfter(curr, next, opts) {
      var slide;
      slide = opts.currSlide + 1;
      var caption1 = (slide) + '&nbsp;/&nbsp;' + opts.slideCount;
      $('#caption').html(caption1);
    }
```

My slide is work. But count is 1 / 3. It is false. As should be 1/4.

Whats my problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The index of slideCount probably starts at 0.  Do this, similar to how you deal with currSlide+1:

```
  var caption1 = (slide) + '&nbsp;/&nbsp;' + (opts.slideCount + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you. It is now 1 / 4. But when I'm not seen 4/4. Its return 3/4

Comment: I don't really understand what your code is doing. Can you show a working fiddle?

Comment: See my post. Have a fiddle link.